# Symfony - Sonata Abstract Admin and getDoctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata

I want to use the prePersist() hook to set a fetched object into a ready-to-be-persisted object. But I can't figure how to use doctrine with Sonata Admin Bundle.

Here is my code :

```
    namespace ShareBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;



class UserShareAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('quantity', 'text')
            ->add('user', 'sonata_type_model_list');
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('quantity');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('quantity')->addIdentifier('user')->addIdentifier('date');
    }

    public function prePersist($object)
    {
        $shareManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ShareBundle:Share');
        $value = $shareManager->findOneBy(array(), array('date' => 'DESC'));
        $object->setShare($value);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys, so I have figured it out !

I had to specify the orm default entity manager in my service argument

```
#app/config/services.yml

arguments: [~, ShareBundle\Entity\UserShare, ~, @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager]
```

And I had to extend the construct function in my Admin class.

```
 public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, $em)
{
    parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

(Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330036/no-entity-manager-in-custom-class-and-contexterrorexception/28331068#28331068))